# Jssor Slider - Image slider (cannot drag pictures) is not working after recreating the slider

Tags: jssor

I'm developing a webpage for that contains Jssor slider.  I'm using jssor.slider-27.5.0.min.js.  The webpage also have daterange picker.  I have button that generate Jssor slider based on selected dates.

At default, the webpage brings images for the past 30 days and show them as Jssor slider. At this point, the slider works fine.  When the Jssor slider generator is clicked, the existing Jssor slider is removed using $("#jssor_1").html("").  Then another Jssor slider is created and correct image is shown on the webpage.  However, I cannot change/drag pictures.

Can you please help me to resolve my issue?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply clear inner html will break the dom hierarchy of elements, it doesn't work.

You can use `$AppendSlides(slidesHtml[, slideIndex])`, `$RemoveSlides(slideIndices)`, `$ReloadSlides(slidesHtml)` to manage slides.

See https://www.jssor.com/development/api-methods-properties-events.html